# web references calling error when add certificate

Tags: asp.net, web-services, certificate

I have web references calling in my asp.net application
When we add certificate to th web service and add the folowing rows to the calling,
I got an error when calling the service:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

The certificate adding:

```
X509Certificate objCert = new X509Certificate();
objCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\cert\\cert.dp.local.cer");
service.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have to add the folowing row before calling the web service:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```